# How to test policy with a variable inside the IAM Policy Simulator

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, policies

The goal is to create a policy that allows S3 upload, but only to a subfolder with a name of uploader's Cognito `sub` identifier: `upload-bucket/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*`. As [described here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html).

I'm trying to create the proper policy with help of the [IAM Policy Simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com).

Here's the problem that I face:

[image]

I don't understand the error, so I have no idea where to go from here.